# Security implications of using a plaintext master password as the salt for PBKDF2 in a zero-knowledge system

Tags: passwords, pbkdf2

I was reading the [BitWarden Security Whitepaper](https://bitwarden.com/images/resources/security-white-paper-download.pdf) (BitWarden is an open source, zero-knowledge password manager that performs encryption/decryption on the client side) and came across the following statement:

> A Master Password hash is also generated using PBKDF-SHA256 with a
> payload of Master Key and with a salt of the Master Password.

At first, it sounds like this could lead to deterministic outputs (where two users with the same password receive the same hashed master key), but earlier in the paper it says that the master key is generated using PBKDF2, passing in the master password, and the email address of the user as a salt (and there's some key stretching as well). So the output of the master password hash should still be non-deterministic due to the salt (email for a user) applied when generating the master key.

I'm interpreting the above description as the following occurring on the client side:

```
DK = PBKDF2(password=plaintextMasterPass, salt=emailOfUser) // get the master key
MasterKeyHash = PBKDF2(password=DK, salt=plaintextMasterPass) // hash the key, using the plaintext master pass as the salt
http.post(MasterKeyHash, ...) // send the hash of the master key to the server for authentication purposes
```

Note that in this case, the plaintext master password salt never needs to be stored in a database. The salt (`plaintextMasterPass`) is provided on the client side at the time the vault is being unlocked.

Previously I have always thought about salts as not needing to be kept secret, so when I read that secret data is being used, something felt a bit off.

Are there any security implications regarding using secret data such as a plaintext master password as the salt input for PBKDF2?